# Find work done in moving charge $q$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential, work

> If charge is distributed uniformly in the $xy$ plane with charge density $+\rho$ in the first quadrant and $-\rho$ in the remaining three quadrants then the work done by the electric field in moving a point charge $q$ from $(0,0,d)$ to $(0,0,2d)$ is .....?

I tried using simple ${\rm d}V=-{\bf E}\cdot {\rm d}{\bf x}$ but I couldn't get the answer. A hint would be enough

Comment: Which $\textbf{E}$ are using you for that?

Comment: Assuming the 4 quadrants to be infinite sheets and using the above formula

Answer (score 1):

Split the $xy$ plane into 4 quadrants, the total electric field is the sum of the fields generated by each of the quadrants. In general for a plane with charge density $\sigma$ the electric field is $\sigma/\epsilon_0$, so that

$$
{\bf E} = -\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}\hat{\bf z} + 3\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}\hat{\bf z} = 2\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}\hat{\bf z}
$$

The change in potential is then

$$
\Delta V = \int_{d}^{2d}{\rm d}z~\hat{\bf z}\cdot 2\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}\hat{\bf z} = \frac{2\rho}{\epsilon_0}\int_d^{2d}{\rm d}z = \frac{2\rho d}{\epsilon_0}
$$

To calculate the work you need a charge $q$: $W = q\Delta V$

Answer (score 0):

We know for a infinite charged sheet electric field is sigma/2epsilon. This is only applicable when we assume point charge is kept anywhere on the z axis and +sigma charge density is present in all the four quadrant. Then due to symmetry we can say that due to each quadrant ,electric field is sigma/8epsilon on that charge. With this method your answer would come out to be (-sigma×q×d)/4epsilon. Hope it helps!